# heroku run rails db:migrate

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

After doing `heroku run rails db:migrate`, I got this error amongst the stacktrace:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation
>   "categories" does not exist: 
>       CREATE TABLE "products" ("id" serial primary key, "title" character varying, "description" character varying, "category_id"
>   integer, "picture" character varying, "video" character varying,
>   "created_at" 
>       timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_fb915499a4"
>
> FOREIGN KEY ("category_id") REFERENCES "categories" ("id"))

Then I ran `heroku run:detached rake db:migrate` and it worked.

But when I go to the site's url, I got this error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in WelcomeController#index
>
> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "products" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT "products".* FROM "products" ORDER BY "products"."cr... ^ : SELECT "products".* FROM "products" ORDER BY "products"."created_at" ASC LIMIT $1

Edit:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

Also the error points to this line:

```
@all_products = Product.order(created_at: :asc).last(4)
```

Defined in `application_controller.rb` like so:

```
 def getProducts
  @all_products = Product.order(created_at: :asc).last(4)
 end
```

The `@all_products` variable was used in `welcome/index.html.erb` to display the last 4 uploaded products.

It was called like so:

```
<div class="text-center">
 <% if @all_products.present? %>
  <% @all_products.each do |p| %>
    <a href="<%= p.picture() %>" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="example-gallery" data-title="<%= p.title %>">
        <%= image_tag(p.picture.url, size: '200x200', class: 'rounded') %>
    </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;    
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: see the update above

Comment: another update above

Comment: Do you have records in the database?

Comment: How are you calling this in your view?

Comment: see the update above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `rake db:migrate` runs in a one-off process, your web process will have already booted and cached the original DB schema, you need to restart your app following the migration being run to recache the new schema.

Comment: you must be a beast